# I need to save a CGContextRef to a file and restore them later

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics

I am building an app that currently has drawings. I need to save each subview and load them later. I know I can be saving them as UIImage but what I want is to save the context and use them later. I am not sure if this possible. Should I simply be saving the CGRect, rotation angle and other properties and re draw them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to save the context itself. You need to save any customised attributes of the context itself and all of the model data used to draw content into the context. This is your true model data. The context itself is just a way of rendering that model data to the screen.